# Support for .so .dex .jar in Android Expansion file

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk-expansion-files

I am uploading an apk that contains .so .dex .jar files. Because of such extra files, apk is exceeding play store limit.

I would like to let this file get separately downloaded as expansion file .obb. The query is .so  .dex  .jar is allowed to be bundled in .obb ?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot place executable files (.so, .dex, .jar) into OBB (expansion files). This is not a technical limitation, it is a policy one, and for good reason.

Expansion files are stored on untrusted storage (for example, sometimes on an SD card). A malicious app might be able to alter the expansion files and change your code after it was downloaded. For this reason, it is unsafe to put any executable code in an expansion file, and so Google Play policy does not allow it.

You may want to look at [dynamic feature modules](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure#dynamic_feature_modules) as one way of reducing your app size through delivery of dynamic code.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot place library files(.so .dex .jar) in .obb extensions. Because compiler need them while running/compiling the code.

Otherwise, anything you place in drawables or in assets can be put into APK expansion files.